# SQL - Update same table based on a condition in WHERE

Tags: sql

I have a requirement to write an SP something like below. This SP is called every second from a .net windows service app.

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID  
  FROM TABLE  
 WHERE GETDATE() < ExpirationDate  
ORDER BY ID
```

If `GetDate() > ExpirationDate` update the record column with a value.

I do not want to do the below as every time the SP is called, it looks at the whole table for update.
I only want to update the record the SP is currently looking at.

```
UPDATE [TableName]   
SET fiel1=1 , field2 = 'abc'  
WHERE ExpirationDate > GETDATE()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to explain more fully what you require as its not currently clear.

Comment: Which DBMS, oracle, mysql or SQL server, also why are you doing top 1?Update table1 set col = val where getdate() < expirationdate

Comment: I think that what you need is a simple update clause. Something like `update TABLE set COLUMN = VALUE where CONDITION.

Comment: I hope its help :

    UPDATE [TableName] SET fiel1=1 , field2 = 'abc'      ........   WHERE   ExpirationDate  > GETDATE()

Comment: @Tess, can you explain more fully why you only want a single record to be updated?

Comment: So which DBMS is it? Based on the `[..]` "quoting" this looks like SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

Use an Update/Select. Depending upon how your SQL instance is configured, you might have to wrap the inner select with the second example below

```
UPDATE [TableName] SET [TableName].fiel1= 1 , [TableName].field2 = 'abc'
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID
     FROM TABLE
     WHERE GETDATE() < ExpirationDate
    ORDER BY ID
) a
where [TableName].ID = a.ID
```

Might have to try this:

```
UPDATE [TableName] SET [TableName].fiel1= 1 , [TableName].field2 = 'abc'
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM (
          SELECT TOP 1 ID
          FROM TABLE
          WHERE GETDATE() < ExpirationDate
          ORDER BY ID
       ) b
     ) a
where [TableName].ID = a.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This will update the single row value you return in your original script:

```
UPDATE [table]
SET 
    Field1 = 1,
    Field2 = abc
WHERE ID = 
  (
    SELECT MIN(ID)
    FROM [table]
    WHERE GETDATE() < ExpirationDate 
  )
```